# Detect touch on UIWebView but ignore swipe or touch on interactive elements (link or onclick)

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

My app holds a full screen UIWebView. A touch on the UIWebView on should fade in/out a ToolBar. But this fade in/out should only happen when tapping on non interactive elements or items.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question's answer: [Does UIGestureRecognizer work on a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview/2909910#2909910)