# iPhone - How may I catch a tap into a UIWebView or a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uiweb

I have a View generated like this :

```
oneView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y , w, h)];
oneView.tag = i;

UITapGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap2:)];
[recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[oneView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[recognizer release];

- (void)handleSingleTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    int viewID = recognizer.view.tag;
    NSLog(@"id : %d", viewID);
}
```

This works, but if I replace the UIView alloc with a UIWebView or UIImageView alloc, then touch event is not triggerred anymore.

How may I make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

set userInteractionEnabled=YES and if needed multipleTouchEnabled=YES

Comment: A webview has those two properties set to yes by default, else you wouldn't be able to use the browser inside.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about the `UIWebView` I suggest you have a look at **drawnonward's** Answer :

[Does UIGestureRecognizer work on a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview)

And for the UIImageView Part see this Tutorial:

[UIImageView-with-zooming-tapping](http://cocoadevblog.com/iphone-tutorial-uiimage-with-zooming-tapping-rotation)

***I could not paste the code here but i think this will keep this area cleaner and easier to read.***

Answer (score 0):

you must override

`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;`

delegate function and return YES;