# How can I detect an onclick event of the whole body element in uiwebview of iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, onclick

The html page goes like this:   `<body onclick="doSomething();">...</body>`

It works fine in chrome or firefox, yet no response in UIWebView of iOS.Is it banned by Apple or something? Or if there any way to work around it?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<body ontouchend="doSomething();">
```

Reference:
[1] [Event handling documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) 
[2] [Does UIGestureRecognizer work on a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview/2909910#2909910)

Comment: Important for my case: I need to have my element include onclick="void(0)" so that the UIWebView knows that the element is clickable at all.