# How to pass touch event to another object?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, touch

I referenced the apps called "Comic Strip" and "Balloon Stickies Free"

When i add a speech balloon and touch s.b or s.b's tail, it works. But when i touch tail's around or between s.b and s.b's tail, it doesn't work. And Photo gets touch and works below the s.b.

So i tried to use `hitTest:withEvent.`

It works when i touch rectangle or tailRect first time. But when i touch other place in the object, and i touch rectangle or tailRect again, it doesn't work.

So how to modify this code ? i don't know .. help me please

```
- (id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(rectangle, currentPt)==YES || CGRectContainsPoint(tailRect, currentPt)==YES)
        return hitView;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding  `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` instead.

Or take a look at [Ole Begemann's OBShapedButton](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/). Code can easily be modified
to work with UIView instead of UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

See this post [horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339381/swipe-html-pagesload-another-html-page-if-i-swipe-horizontal). Using this code you can get all touch events in a single UIWindow class. You have to write some code to pass control appropriately.