# UIWebView, enable touch hold save image,

Tags: webview, touch

this is my code but not working

```
`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2;
```

```
[self.webview addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
```

}

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
  if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {
      NSLog(@"Long Press");

  //do something

  }
  }`

Comment: This was discussed some time back over here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview