# UIwebView load animation image not respond to UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview

I use `UIWebView` as a subView of `UIView` to load animation image(GIF) from server.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picLink]]];
```

And I add Tap gesture to my `UIView`, but the webView disable this gesture(`UIWebView frame` = `UIView Frame` and `[view sendSubViewToBack:webView]`.

How to solve it? Is there another method to display GIF image. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does UIGestureRecognizer work on a UIWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a sibling UIView on top of the UIWebView and add the tap gesture recognizer to that sibling. The code might look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
    [containerView addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/eezCO.gif"]]];

    UIView *frontView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
    [containerView addSubview:frontView];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [frontView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"tapped");
}
```