# WebView and UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to have a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` that is attached to a webview. This works, but I need to also be able to scroll up and down the web view.

**Here is my code:**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upSwipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction)];
upSwipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
upSwipeGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:upSwipeGesture];

[webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:upSwipeGesture];
```

If I comment out the last line, then the webview scrolls but the gesture is not recognized. If I do not comment out the last line, then the gesture is recognized but the webview does not scroll.

I would like to be able to scroll and have the gesture be recognized. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does UIGestureRecognizer work on a UIWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview)

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView has its own private views, which also has gesture recognizers attached. Hence, precedence rules keep any gesture recognizers added to a UIWebView from working properly.

One option is to implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol and implement the method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`. Return YES from this method for other tap gestures.

This way you'll get your tap handler called, and the web view will still get its called.

Try this,

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upSwipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction)];
upSwipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
upSwipeGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
upSwipeGesture.delegate=self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:upSwipeGesture];
```

ind implement this delegate method,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```