# Double Tap Recognition over UIWebView - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement Gesture recognizer over UIWebView to detect double taps. But there is no recognition.

I have looked over web for a few tutorials and I could compile to this. Code below. But there is no success.

```
class PageContentViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var pageIndex: Int = 0
var strTitle: String!
var flag : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let req = URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.strTitle+"/index" , ofType: "html")!))
    self.webView.loadRequest(req)
    self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

    }

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.goToback))
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate? = self
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    webView.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    webView.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(tapGestureRecognizer)
}


func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer,  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive:UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}


func goToback(){
    print("On the Back")
}

}
```

[image: This picture contains webview in orange]
[image: Attribute Inspector for UIWebView]

What is wrong in the code.?

I'm noob to swift.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview

Comment: @RichardG I want to doubletap on the UIWebView to change the view controller. But UIWebView does not detect any tap gesture.

Comment: no need of this `self.view.addSubview(self.webView)` and add the `webView.delegate = self`

Comment: pl. check that userInteraction is enabled or not.

Comment: @RichardG yes it is enabled in attribute inspector too.

Comment: also pl. make sure that whether IBOutlet is attached correctly or not.

Comment: @RichardG It is working for data displaying so I believe yes it is attached correctly :)

Comment: see my answer...I think it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to add

```
webView.delegate = self
```

Also add UIWebViewDelegate to your class

Edit:

Your shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith and shouldReceive look a bit weird maybe a copy paste mistake? It should look like:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive:UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Edit 2:

I copied your exact code and removed gestureRecognizerShould begin and it worked, I was able to remove some other code as well, not sure if you needed it in your project but here is what works with me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let req = URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.strTitle+"/index" , ofType: "html")!))
        self.webView.loadRequest(req)
    }

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.goToback))
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}


func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer,  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}


func goToback() {
    print("On the Back")
}
```

Comment: Hey @Casper Zandbergen Added delegate and assigned to self. but still the issue remains

Comment: Hmm not sure why this wouldnt work but I checked an old project and the way I did it is adding the GestureRecognizer to the scrollView of the webView: `webView.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)` I also set the scrollview delegate to self

Comment: Could you mind checking if there is some change required with Interface builder.

Comment: Hey @Casper Can you share your email ? or any place we can connect to?

Comment: If the code in my answer didn't help you I don't know if I can help you any further, I'm sorry. @Prateekro

Comment: Hey @Casper Ok. I'll dig in more to find out if anything comes up. thanks :)

Comment: @Prateekro You havent added the first part of my answer yet

Comment: Thanks a lot Casper it works finally it took me 2 days searching for that answer well done

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using same gesture `UIGestureRecognizer` for `webview` and `webview.scrollview`.

Instead you need to create two separate `UIGestureRecognizer` for both like this...

```
// for webView
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.goToback))
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate? = self
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

// for webView.scrollView
let tapGestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.goToback))
tapGestureRecognizer1.delegate? = self
tapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
 webView.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer1)
```

If you you assign same gesture recognizer to two object then one of the object doesn't have it...see log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a double tap gesture working in my app by doing the following:

I created a subclass of UIWebView that is the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

```
class MyWebView: UIWebView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer,  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive:UITouch) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then in my View Controller class I reference my subclass (make sure it is referenced in Interface Builder also)

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: MyWebView!
```

And in viewDidLoad add the recognizer

```
 let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(self.goToback))
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate? = self.webView //set the delegate to the custom UIWebView
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Hope this helps, my original code was in Objective-C code so had to do a quick translation here so hope there are no syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code and it works for me flawlessly

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapLockGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLock))    
    tapLockGesture.delegate = self
    tapLockGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapLockGesture)

}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

make sure you conform to **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** and **UIScrollViewDelegate**.

Comment: Hey @aryan could you mind adding a screenshot of your UI Hierarchy? or view hierarchy?