# UIGesturerecognizer not calling shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Heres the code where im adding the gesture recognizers

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:media.thumbnailPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];  
    imageView.image = img;  
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    imageView.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];  

    //Add tap guesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTap setDelegate:self];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [doubleTap setDelegate:self];

    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
```

and i have implemented the

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
     NSLog(@"Gesturing");
     return YES;
}
```

but the delegate method is not called when dealing with the singletap gesture but it works for doubletap gesture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Simultaneous gesture recognizers in Iphone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319426/1378447)

> For most cases you don't need to:
>
> ```
> setup a delegate
> permit simultaneous gesture recognition (unless you want simultaneous swipes; not likely)
> ```

Setting Gesture Recognizers

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                     initWithTarget:self 
                                     action:@selector(handleSingleTapOnMainImageView:)];

[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                     initWithTarget:self 
                                     action:@selector(handleDoubleTapOnMainImageView:)];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[doubleTap release];
```

Method implementation

```
-(void)handleSingleTapOnMainImageView:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureView
{
NSLog(@"handleSingleTapOnMainImageView");
}

-(void)handleDoubleTapOnMainImageView:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureView
{
NSLog(@"handleDoubleTapOnMainImageView");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` would be work!