# iCarousel item pinch and pan

Tags: ios, objective-c, zooming, uigesturerecognizer, icarousel

I'm trying to implement a zoom feature for an `iCarousel` item view. This is my code :

```
NSString *pathToHDImage = [documentsFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:solution.localHDURL];

if (!view) {

    view = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    pinchGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false;

    pinchGesture.delegate = panGesture.delegate = self;

    [view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    ((AsyncImageView *)view).imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToHDImage];
} else
    ((AsyncImageView *)view).imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToHDImage];
```

The problem is that my `handlePan:` and `handlePinch:` never get called. How can I do? The main goal is to implement zoom feature for every `iCarousel` item view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
    {
    return YES;
    }
```

I did not test but I hope it helps. 
In case it does not work check out this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315676/adding-custom-gesture-to-icarousel-items?rq=1) and then this [link2](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate#jumpTo_5)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help, no changes