# StarRating inside scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am using `RatingView` library for implementing the star rating in my app, but the `delegate` method when rating is changed is not called.

My rating view is inside a `UIScrollView`, when the rating view is taken outside the `UIScrollView` ,the delegate is called when rating is changed.

I have tried `EDStarRating` also but same issue.

Any Fix ?

Comment: Do you set the delegate for your ratingView ? Like so:     `self.ratingView.delegate = self;`? Please try to provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the implementation of `RatingView`. It is implemented with an `UIGestureRecognizer`.

The scrollview also has a UIGestureRecognizer which conflicts. You can solve your problem by overriding this method and returning YES:

```
gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

Also here is a SO Thread which covers using multiple UIGestureRecognizers:
[Simultaneous gesture recognizers in Iphone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627934/simultaneous-gesture-recognizers-in-iphone-sdk)